# Obtener las fechas de los días Lunes dependiendo de un rango de fechas PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

Dependiendo de un rango de fechas quiero obtener sólo las fechas de los días Lunes, tengo la siguiente función que funciona pero me trae las fechas repetidas:

```
$fechaInicio=strtotime("2016-08-01");
$fechaFin=strtotime("2016-08-20");

//Recorro las fechas y con la función strotime obtengo los lunes
for($i=$fechaInicio; $i<=$fechaFin; $i+=86400){
  echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday this week', $i))."<br>";
}
```

El resultado que me da es este, que esta bien porque me trae las fechas que son, pero salen repetidas:

```
2016-08-01<br>2016-08-01<br>2016-08-01<br>2016-08-01<br>
2016-08-08<br>2016-08-08<br>2016-08-08<br>2016-08-08<br>
2016-08-15<br>2016-08-15<br>2016-08-15<br>2016-08-15<br>
```

y quiero que salgan así:

```
2016-08-01<br>2016-08-08<br>2016-08-15<br>
```

Lo que no quiero es usar una función aparte para que me elimine los duplicados, me gustaría saber si puedo mejorar lo que estoy haciendo o saber si hay una mejor forma de traer la fecha de los días lunes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siguiendo tu código y manteniendo la lógica que deseas, tan solo tendrías que multiplicar por 7 la constante de día que utilizas en el for, para que haga un "cálculo" por semana:

```
$fechaInicio = strtotime("2016-08-01");
$fechaFin = strtotime("2016-08-20");

//Recorro las fechas y con la función strotime obtengo los lunes
for ($i = $fechaInicio; $i <= $fechaFin; $i += 86400 * 7){
    echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday this week', $i)).'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Fabian Sierra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/10097/fabian-sierra) Puede usar este fragmento mejorado

```
$fechaInicio=strtotime("2016-08-01");
$fechaFin=strtotime("2016-08-20");
//Recorro las fechas y con la función strotime obtengo los lunes
for($i=$fechaInicio; $i<=$fechaFin; $i+=86400){
    //Sacar el dia de la semana con el modificador N de la funcion date
    $dia = date('N', $i);
    if($dia==1){
        echo "Lunes. ". date ("Y-m-d", $i)."<br>";
    }
}
```

Prueba

Comment: Puedes ademas de validar el dia lunes aplicando para cualquier otro dia. Solo modificar la linea `if($dia == 1)` a un valor de entre 1 y 7 (Lunes a Domingo

Comment: como puedo obtener el miercoles

Comment: Puedes usar `if($dia == 3)` para verificar si es Miércoles